# Is Google BigQuery sufficient for financial statement storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I didn't fully know what to make the title, since this a complex situation. I'm currently working on a project to retrieve financial statements (invoices) for a company from their Erply database, using Erply's API, then transferring that data to another database to do some light analytics on it with Google Data Studio. I currently have a google cloud function up and running that retrieves the data and stores it in Google BigQuery.

The main issues:

1. BigQuery is append-only and I need to be updating the data in BigQuery at least daily, with only new entries.
2. The Erply API only allows one to retrieve (a maximum of) 100 invoices through a single API call, then the next 100 can be retrieved, but there is no way of knowing how many invoices there are in total (thus, when to stop calling) or which invoices are new since the last retrieval. (I don't expect to receive a solution to this on this thread, but just thought I'd give all the information)
3. I've used BigQuery's automatic schema generator by giving it a json file containing about 20 invoices, however, the data I'm pulling from Erply seems to not always adhere strictly to this schema (they all have the same exact same keys, but aren't always filled with the correct format for the values) thus I'm getting a Partial Error Failure when trying to push the data to BigQuery (due to a lot of invoices not fitting the schema exactly). **Example given below in code-block.** I can't figure out this error message and would like to see a more in-depth explanation for each failure to try and narrow down the key-value pairs which vary in format and causes the errors.

In the end, I need to use BigQuery, as it directly connects to Google Data Studio leading to a very convenient and easy to use setup (once the data is actually inside BigQuery). What I am wondering is, for the above-mentioned issues, should I be importing the data straight into BigQuery? Or should I be using another GCP storage option and linking that to BigQuery?

Any answers for the individual issues would also be appreciated, and let me know if you need any more information.

```
{ PartialFailureError
    at request (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/table.js:1550:23)
    at Util.handleResp (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:142:9)
    at retryRequest (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:417:22)
    at onResponse (/srv/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:206:7)
    at /srv/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:208:13
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  errors: 
   [ { errors: [Array], row: [Object] },
     { errors: [Array], row: [Object] },
     { errors: [Array], row: [Object] },
     { errors: [Array], row: [Object] } ],
  name: 'PartialFailureError',
  response: 
   { kind: 'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse',
     insertErrors: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  message: '' }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let your rows to be imported multiple times. We always do this. Then we have a view eg: table_last which picks the most recent row from the storage table. This view can be used further in reports, or can be materialized using scheduled queries to a new table.
   So the recommendation here is to learn how to deal with multiple rows and you will be saved.
2. Erply has pagination build inside the API, so you just paginate 100 at a time until you reach the end.

> pageNo -  API returns at most recordsOnPage items at a time. To
>   retrive the next recordsOnPage items, send a new request with pageNo
>   incremented by one. By default, API returns "page 1".

https://learn-api.erply.com/requests/getsalesdocuments

3. For this one, you should parse and normalize to the format that BQ accepts at the ingest point if that is a Cloud Function do it there. Also you can do a trick, that if you catch the error in the Cloud Function you forward that to another GCF that deals with normalization and that will process the bad rows.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick and insightful response! A follow-up question: I don't know if you know Erply or whether you just researched it for this thread, but I see no way of finding the total number of pages through Erply's API, that's why I didn't want to use that method. So how would you write that code? Some sort of while loop with a catch for when there are no more pages and it encounters an error had occurred to me, but that doesn't seem like very good programming etiquette.

Comment: Read here: https://learn-api.erply.com/requests/getsalesdocuments pageNo  API returns at most recordsOnPage items at a time. To retrive the next recordsOnPage items, send a new request with pageNo incremented by one. By default, API returns "page 1".

Comment: This technique is called scrolling, and you go until you find the API returning fewer results than the recordsOnPage items.

Answer (score 0):

I've also figured out part of my question, in terms of the Partial Failure Error and getting more detailed information out of it. This might be obvious, but it wasn't to me and it might help someone else:

```
await bigqueryClient
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .insert(rows)
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error['errors'][0]);
    });
```

When catching the error while inserting the rows into BigQuery, you can select certain parts of the error to display them in more detail. This specific selection showed me round about what the issues were when inserting.